# Long HttpClient execution time after Thread.Sleep(80000+)

Tags: c#, http, dotnet-httpclient, .net-6.0

If the pause between two requests is less than 80 seconds, request execution time about 400-700 ms. But if the pause is more than 80 seconds, execution time about 1000-1500 (like first request). Why?

```
using System.Diagnostics;

var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var watch = new Stopwatch();

watch.Start();
var data1 = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://google.com");
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"{data1.StatusCode} {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
watch.Reset();

Thread.Sleep(10000);

watch.Start();
var data2 = await httpClient.GetAsync("https://google.com");
watch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"{data2.StatusCode} {watch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");
```

I get **OK 1319 | OK 457**. When I change Thread.Sleep(10000) to Thread.Sleep(85000), I get **OK 1399 | OK 1183**. This is very bad for my Telegram bot. When no one has used it for 80+ seconds, bot takes a long time to respond.

Comment: Probably underlying OS is closing TCP connection after 60 seconds of inactivity therefore a new connection must be established for second request from the very beginning.

Comment: It is possible that you hit some kind of timeout (TCP?) and you have to reconnect, which together with TLS may take significant time. You can try making dummy requests every 10s or so, to keep the connection alive. Maybe they won't block you. You can also try HTTP/3, if the other end supports it.